# Probability distribution of the difference of two random variables from the distribution of the ratio of two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. We only know the distribution of $X/Y$ and nothing else. Is it possible to derive the distribution of $X-Y$ from this?

Coming to a specific case, suppose we know that $X/Y$ follows a uniform distribution from 1 to 2. Can we know the distribution of $X-Y$ from this?

If not, what additional information is required for us to be able to find out the distribution of $X-Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be a random variable following any distribution and let $U$ be uniform on $(0,1)$. Define $R:=U+1$, $Y:=D/U$, and $X:=Y+D$. Then $X/Y=R$ and $X-Y=D$.